# What do cars do with their passengers?

Tags: word-request

What do cars do with their passengers? They can "transport" them, but I don't like the word. I doubt they "carry" them: people are not their cargo. Do they "drive" them?

Comment: *Transport* is the most common word by far, and what most people would say. But cars do also *carry* people. As far as the car (or any other vehicle) is concerned, passengers *are* just cargo. (And people can carry people too, even when the person being carried is not considered cargo. *Carry* does not apply only to cargo.) Only a self-driving car could be considered to drive people.

Comment: I drove all those people in my car.

Comment: The snarky answer is that cars (unless they are self-driving) don't *do* anything with their passengers except **contain** them.  Cars have no volition or ability to act on their own, which is I think why you're having trouble coming up with a verb that feels right.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Unless I am extremely wrong we can say "This bus will take you to the airport".

Comment: @SovereignSun That's why I said I was being "snarky" (that is, not entirely serious).  That said, when you say "this bus", that can be a metonym for the the bus route that was designed by a human being with volition, not the actual bus itself.

Comment: “...people are not their cargo.” Yes, they are. In most cases, they are self-loading cargo. So, cars can transport people. 

Comment: For someone who speaks English, it is usually awkward to say, "the car carried my friends to my neighborhood", because it seems as though the car is an agent (it makes an idea and follows a plan) and the friends are passive. We say instead, "my friends drove a car" or "my friends came by car". However, if we discuss an event that is repeated, planned, or abstract, then we may use "the train takes you to London", or "this model airplane carries ten passengers". For specific events, we may use the active form, if the machine performs the task automatically, for example, "the phone rang".

Comment: (In cases when we identity no human or other agent to have control over a vessel,  we may explain the events as though the vessel is the agent, as in "we drifted for two days before our raft carried us close enough to shore to be seen".)

Comment: @JasonBassford Fill the blank: 'The car that __ the terrorist leader was destroyed in an airstrike carried out by ally forces.'

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev *The car that **transported** that terrorist …* It's still the most natural of the possible words.

Comment: @JasonBassford What if, as I said, I don't like this word?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Then you have to use a word you do like. But I don't believe it will be the most natural for most people.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev: "Carried" would be a very natural choice for the sentence, more so than "transported" in my opinion. (However, since the airstrike interrupted the trip, "was carrying" would be even more natural.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most obviously cars (and other ground vehicles) can transport, carry and even take passengers wherever they need to go. They can also help them get to whatever place they need (help get to).

I am not very much sure but probably "ferrying" could also work for a ground vehicle.

Comment: I saw a pickup truck hauling some people to the store (they were sitting in the truck bed).  I'm pretty sure hauling people is discouraged.

Comment: Yes, but we only use this active form in English when we describe an event that is abstract. We may say, "The car can carry 5 people", but not, "the car carried my friends", because saying so it English attributes agency or intentionality to the car.

Comment: @epl Imagine Tesla without a driver, you get in and say "Tesla, take me to the hotel Amasada!", which sounds quite natural in my opinion, "Tesla, transport me to the airport" - sounds strange but okay. "Tesla, carry me over to my dad's house" - also sounds okay.

Comment: @SovereignSun: I get that. When it happens, post another comment here, to remind me to delete mine. The distinction is that in most cases in English we use language that attributes agency to an object only if that object performs tasks automatically, rather than through direct initiation or control by actual agents. Computers, robots, even alarm clocks and dishwashers may take language that attributes agency, because they appear in some sense to be agents, as cars do not  do (yet) with respect to travel.

Comment: @epl We are discouraged from attributing agency.  It doesn't belong in your masters degree thesis. If someone told me they saw a pickup truck hauling people to the field, the comment would sound natural.  What do pickups trucks do?  They haul things.  What are pickup trucks for?  They are for hauling things.

Comment: @EllieK: If the agent is more distant from the observer than the mechanism, then it may seem natural to attribute agency to the mechanism (e.g. "the phone rang"). If the agent is near, then it is very unnatural. To someone outside a vehicle it is natural to say, "the car stopped at the signal". For those inside, "the car stopped" indicates malfunction or collision. Otherwise, "the driver stopped [the car] at the traffic signal".

Comment: @epl That's an excellent observation.  Perhaps the difference is not created by distance but by the existence of the *actual agent*.  When the driver becomes part of the scene, the car is stopped by the driver.  When the driver is concealed within the car, or perhaps does not exist at all, the car stops.

Comment: @EllieK It all is not entirely true, take this example:"The taxi driver was taking her to the hotel then suddenly the car stopped. He pulled over to check on his passenger."

Comment: @SovereignSun  I'm not sure your sentence works.  There exist contextual inconsistencies making it confusing.  Which car stopped?  The car he was driving?  If it stopped, how did he pull over?  I think if you extrapolate the sentence you will find that the car did not stop [moving forward] but that its engine stopped [running].  An engine can most certainly stop without our having to ascribe intentionality.  It's happened to me before.

Comment: @EllieK: I may not understand, but it seems that you may be conflating remoteness with nonexistence. All competent narrators assume that a traveling car has a driver, as long as such is the common understanding of cars.  The engineer of a train is remote, even while assumed to exist, and therefore, "the train stopped". Also, I emphasize remoteness over being inside a scene, because remoteness is subjective. A narrator may express confusion over a decision of the driver, by metaphorically shifting agency from the driver to the car, thus distancing the observation from its causing agent.

Comment: @epl I understand a car has a driver and that a competent narrator keeps that in mind.  Speakers, unlike narrators however, need not and often are not competent and as a result they just open their mouths and speak.  Cars stop at stop signs, buses haul people, trains change directions, and bicycles drive off sidewalks without an inkling of intention of their own.

Comment: @EllieK: I don't mean "competent narrator" as in contrast to the general population, but rather as to include it. Everyone with normal cognitive function intuitively recognizes that a traveling car has a driver, and natural speakers of English reflect this understanding in their speech, as well as their relationship with the driver. If a friend told you that a car "stopped", would you understand that your friend believed no one was driving it, or only that the driver was out of site? As long as your friend understands that a driver existed, then your friend is a competent narrator.